# OpenCV pipe to gstreamer RTMP stream

Tags: c++, opencv, youtube, gstreamer, rtmp

I am trying to live stream the output of my opencv program to youtube. I tried using ffmpeg in c++, which seemed very complicated, I did not find a way to add an audio stream, which is a requirement for youtube. At the moment I'm trying to use gstreamer.

My approach is based on this example: [Opening a GStreamer pipeline from OpenCV with VideoWriter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43412797/opening-a-gstreamer-pipeline-from-opencv-with-videowriter). 
However I have not been able to create a gstream command that actually does something. I ma trying to implement the following approach to add an audio track: [GStreamer: Add dummy audio track to the received rtp stream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37904594/gstreamer-add-dummy-audio-track-to-the-received-rtp-stream).

```
gst-launch-1.0 videotestsrc | mux. audiotestsrc wave=silence freq=200 | voaacenc | aacparse | mux. mpegtsmux name=mux | rtmpsink location=rtmp://a.rtmp.youtube.com/live2/stream
```

Does anybody know how I should go about creating my required gstreamer command?